# JS function parameter outer environment

Tags: javascript, function, environment

I have a question regarding the outer environment in JS. Suppose I have the code like this:

```
function callbackTest(callback) {
  var a = 1;
  callback();
}
callbackTest(function() {
  console.log(a);
});
```

The brower told me that a is not defined. It means the outer environment is the global context, but I created the function within callbackTest, so I assume the outer environment of callback is the callbackTest. Can somebody tell me why? Thx!

Comment: It doesn’t matter which function calls which, it only matters where the functions are declared. A variable (scoped to a function) can only be accessed by the function the variable is declared in or any inner function nested in that function (declared inside it).

Comment: Scope is determined by where the function is defined, not where it's called.

Answer (score 3):

> but I created the function within callbackTest

No you didn't. The function is created here *outside* of `callbackTest`:

```
callbackTest(function() {
  console.log(a);
});
```

Maybe it's easier to see if you split this into two statements:

```
var f = function() {
  console.log(a);
};
callbackTest(f);
```

The function is created in global scope. It is only *called* inside `callbackTest`. But since JavaScript has lexical scope and not dynamic scope, it cannot access `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `a` is defined inside the scope of the function `callbackTest`. It doesn't matter where you call the function. The scope is still restricted to that function. Even the following would be undefined:

```
function callbackTest() {
  var a = 1;
}
callbackTest();
console.log(a);
```

You must define the variable `a` in outer scope, where all codes share:

```
var a;

function callbackTest(callback) {
  a = 1;
  callback();
}
callbackTest(function() {
  console.log(a);  // Now outputs 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope (environment) of a function is not defined where you call it, it is defined where you created it. Your callback function is defined when you called the **callbackTest** function and not inside its body. That is why the callback is not aware of the variable that is inside, its scope is whatever scope is active when called the **callbackTest** function.